# É correto deixar a responsabilidade do cálculo de frete no front-end?

Tags: aplicação-web, front-end

Todos nós sabemos da agilidade que determinado código escrito no front-end tem e faz com que nossas aplicações fiquem mais rápidas.

Seria correto calcular um frete no front-end da aplicação e mandar esses dados para back-end?

E, no back-end, faríamos novamente uma verificação para validar isso. Claro, sem prejudicar a execução no cliente. Ou seja, totalmente fora (a parte), podendo até mesmo ser implementado em uma fila em determinada hora do dia ou da noite.

Comment: Não é errado! Fazendo desta forma seria bom para o usuário poder simular vários cálculos diferentes... Mas, é necessário fazer o que você disse... Validar tudo no back-end, inclusive re-fazer o cálculo para ver se houve alguma "malandragem".

Comment: Não, porém é necessario fazer um validação final no back-end

Comment: E fazendo assim, você desonera o servidor temporariamente até o usuário escolher o frete ideal.

Comment: Ao invés revisar em determinado horário você pode revisar de maneira assíncrona no back end e dependendo do volume de operações podendo até alocar um servidor específico para não impactar o sistema.

Comment: Sim é o que eu quero a diferença entre o tempo de resposta é gigantesca não dá pra comparar, porem a sempre a necessidade de se ter mais código pois terá que ter duas validações mesmo que isso possa até mesmo ser em determinados casos em horários diferentes.

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que sim.

Seria como validar um campo de senha, por exemplo. Verificamos o tamanho e se é forte no front-end e depois no back-end fazemos outra verificação se está correta para inserir no banco de dados...